# Why does my object change after list::push_back()

Tags: c++, stl

It looks like my object changes after I do a push_back into a std::list.

This is the object before the push_back:
[image: object before push_back]

See how after some valid m_parent_reference pointer it eventually becomes nullptr thus ending the chain.

This is how my object looks after push_back()
[image: object after push_back]

Now there is no nullptr anymore. Instead one parent_reference references its child, creating a neverending loop.

1. `m_InterchangeList` is of type `std::list<CKerEDIInterchange>`
2. `m_parent_reference` is of type `CKerEDIReference`
3. `CKerEDIInterchange` inherits from `CKerEDIReference`
4. Neither `CKerEDIInterchange` nor `CKerEDIReference` have a custom copy constructor
5. I have tested this behaviour with Visual Studio 2010 SP1 and Visual Studio 2012 Update 2
6. The variable m_parent_reference can only be set through the constructor

   ```
          CKerEDIReference(const CKerEDIReference* const parent_reference = NULL)
           : m_parent_reference(parent_reference) {};
   ```

With custom copy constructors and assign operators I could observe the following:

1. Assign Operators are never called
2. The reference given to `CKerEDIReference::CKerEDIReference(const CKerEDIReference&) is already broken as in it already has this neverending loop.

**edit**
More infos:

1. Calling `{CKerEDIInterchange tmp(nInterchange);}` does
   not lead to corrupted objects.
2. Slicing is not involved. m_InterchangeList is of `type
   std::list<CKerEDIInterchange>` and nInterchange if of type
   `CKerEDIInterchange`

I would really like to know if anyone could give me a hint where to look next.

Thanks in advance,
Nick Papagiorgio

Comment: You should not post code which did *not* help reproducing the problem. You should post some code that does show the problem. How are we supposed to figure out what's wrong otherwise?

Comment: Are your parent references pointing to items in `m_InterchangeList` by any chance? Because when the list is internally resized, pointers become invalid.

Comment: No copy constructors but do your classes have destructors?

Comment: @riv, resizing a `std::list` does not make pointers to it invalid. That's one of the points of a `std::list`.

Comment: @AndyProwl I am looking for hints where the problem might lay so I wanted to show that it doesn't look like a trivial problem

Comment: @john virtual destructors are available, though they don't do anything special (just clearing a few lists)

Comment: @NickPapagiorgio Well that sounds very risky. If you have destructors but no copy constructor or assignment operators, you are breaking the 'rule of three'. I would suggest that a temporary copy of your data is being created and then destructed which then has the side effect of modifying your real data.

Comment: I have deleted the body of all destructors (they just called list.clear()), keeping the declaration because of the virtual keyword. The problem remains.

Comment: If you create and initialize a single instance (of whatever type the list holds) with nInterchange, and then destroy that instance again, what happens? E.g. with T being the type, add "{ T tmp(nInterchange); }" in a line before the push_back() call. Also, just to rule out some obvious ones, you are not slicing the object (i.e. storing baseclass instances in the list) and you turned off the optimizer, right?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason fo this behaviour.
Apparently one of those `CKerEDIReference` objects was already deleted. By adding the new object to the list the new listitem was written to the memory of that deleted object. I guess it was just pure coincidence it didn't crash.